# How to find Max value from set of rows and insert a row (increment value by one)

Tags: python, mysql

I have a two columns of data: Course_Num and RecordNum.

Example of output:

```
‘Select Course_Num, RecordNum from Courses where RecordNum in (‘111’, ‘222’, ‘333’)’

Course_Num |  RecordNum
1          |  111
2          |  111
-----------------------
1          |  222
2          |  222
3          |  222
-----------------------
1          |  333
2          |  333
3          |  333
4          |  333
```

I am trying to find the Max(Course_Num) from the result.

So, in this case we have these three outputs.

```
Course_num |  RecordNum
2          |  111
3          |  222
4          |  333
```

I would like to insert one additional row (increment 1 to Course_Num) based upon these outputs.

So, the desired final output would be:

```
Course_Num |  RecordNum
3          |  111
4          |  222
5          |  333
```

I would like to know how to write in Python or/and SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use max()  +1 agroup by RecordNum

```
  select max(course_num) +1, RecordNum
  from my_table 
  group by RecordNum
```

and for insert

```
 insert into my_table (course_num, RecordNum)
 select max(course_num) +1, RecordNum
 from my_table 
 group by RecordNum
```